# Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

Running my springboot web service java jar app on ubuntu server results in the error shown below, I have done a bit of research about the error however I cannot get a solution. The command I am using to run the jar file is

```
java -jar mySpringBootApp.jar
```

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at aacctt.payments.org.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [ mySpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [ mySpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [ mySpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [ mySpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2070) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:173) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Either give permissions to the user to write to tmp or change the tmp directory with the jvm option -Djava.io.tmpdir=<some dir with rw privileges>.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are getting this issue while deploying Spring boot application in Kubernetes, one of configuration worth checking is *readOnlyRootFilesystem*. It must be set to false until you are trying to intentionally run read only containers.

It can be used in deployment config as following:

```yaml
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: hello-world
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false ## this should not be true
```

Comment: What if i want to run container with readOnlyRootFilesystem : true

Answer (score 2):

Try any of the following:

1) Change permissions of /tmp to give access to your user.
chmod -R 777 /tmp
make you sure you run above command with sudo access (root)

2) add the user who is to the sudo group.

Comment: None of that will help.  It's not a permissions problem.  It's a **read-only file system**.

Answer (score 1):

For ones who are getting same exception while running from Intellij IDEA when providing env variables as part of run/debug configuration:
please look if "Include parent environment variables" is checked

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for this is that the root filesystem is full. It was the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! The diskspace assigned to Docker (which is seen internally by it, as a separate hard disk) was full! I increased the space, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are deploying to Kubernetes and you need to set `securityContext.readOnlyRootFilesystem` to `true` you can create tmp dir by mounting volume

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello
          image: hello-world
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
          securityContext:
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      volumes:
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: { }
```

Answer (score 0):

your application user probably does not have sufficient permissions to crate anything in `/tmp` directory ... see last message `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system`

Comment: any idea on how I can give it permission

Comment: at first try if you really don't have permissions... command like `touch /tmp/testfile.txt` could give you a result. If it tells you that you don't have permissions try `chmod 1777 /tmp`

Comment: I get this error when I run the first command ``` touch: cannot touch '/tmp/testfile.txt': Read-only file system ```

Comment: and when I run the last command I get chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp': Read-only file system

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this error is that you not include system environments variables. Maybe you try to define a new configuration with different system variables that are defined in your java IDE and you disable default environments variable.

[image]

Please enable checkbox:
Run/Debug Configuration -> select your configuration -> press on the environment variables -> check Include system environment variables (as in the picture added above).

Keep in mind that you need to check if you have added the path of the Temp file in the system variables.
[image]